# How to order a list in HTML based on the list item id

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I'm sure that this is similar to another question that has been asked, but I looked for a solid hour and couldn't find anything quite right.

I have an un-ordered list where I want the list items to have have an index, so I'm just making their ID to be the index I desire. So it's going to look something like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"> item1 </li>
    <li id="2"> item2 </li>
    <li id="3"> item3 </li>
    <li id="4"> item4 </li>
</ul>
```

Now I have a div that works as a drop down box, which changes the theme of the page as you click on each list item. What I want, is something that will be able to change the id of the list item, and than re-order them so that the selected one is now the first item. So lets assume that I clicked on item3, what I'd ideally like to be the result is something that looks like.

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"> item3 </li>
    <li id="2"> item1 </li>
    <li id="3"> item2 </li>
    <li id="4"> item4 </li>
</ul>
```

Granted, I'm sure there are other ways of doing it, but I'm trying to change the framework of the project as little as possible, so I'm thinking that this is ideally what I want. The content for each item should obviously stay the same, but the id will change based on where in the list it should be. I hope this isn't too obscure, it seems like something that shouldn't be overly hard but I can't figure it out since I'm new to coding JS / html.

Comment: just use value instead of id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript solution:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8MbeY/)**

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var list = ul.children;

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    list[i].onclick = function(){
        if(i > 0){
            ul.removeChild(this);
            ul.insertBefore(this, list[0]);

            for(var j=0; j<list.length; j++){
                list[j].id = j+1;   
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-box layout and `order` property. You can ordering your html elements using only CSS.

Here is a simple snippet:

```css
ul.ordered {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h1>Without Flex</h1>
<ul>
    <li id="4"> item 4 </li>
    <li id="2"> item 2 </li>
    <li id="1"> item 1 </li>
    <li id="3"> item 3 </li>
</ul>

<h1>With Flex Order</h1>
<ul class="ordered">
    <li id="4" style="order: 4"> item 4 </li>
    <li id="2" style="order: 2"> item 2 </li>
    <li id="1" style="order: 1"> item 1 </li>
    <li id="3" style="order: 3"> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Answer (score -1):

Try this logic... It might works...  Please check this [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/soundar24/PnJA5/) for demo..

```
        $('li').on({
            click: function (e) {
                var all = $("#rootUl").children("li");
                var index = all.index($(e.target));
                var current = e.target.innerHTML;

                if (index > 0) {
                    for (var i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        all[i + 1].innerHTML = all[i].innerHTML;
                    }
                }
                all[0].innerHTML = current;
            }
        });
```